# Import a Null value into Acumatica

Tags: null, acumatica, myob

I am trying to import an Null value into Acumatica.  Specifically I am trying to remove the GL Expense Account on a number of Vendor Records.
I have tried, ='', ="", =" ",=' ',=NULL,NULL,='NULL', in the Value field of the import scenario.  I am working with an Excel data source by I have also tried, CSV and hard coding the value in the integration.
None of which see to work.

Answer (score 1):

In acumatica version before 6.1 Update 5 you cannot do what you want. In versions 6.1 update 5 and bigger, you can set in import scenario formula `'=Null'` for field and this field will be nullified.